# JSONPath cannot find keys with null values

Tags: gatling, jsonpath

I sometimes need to parse JSON with null in values like this:

`{"someKey" : null}`

and verify someKey value is null, but that seems impossible:

All other jsonPath are converted to string like this:

```
{"someKey" : 2}
.check(jsonPath("$.someKey").is("2")) //pass
```

but null:

```
{"someKey" : null}
.check(jsonPath("$.someKey").is("null"))
//jsonPath($.extMediaThumbnailId).find(0).is(null), but actually found nothing
```

`.is(null)` check return nullpointer exception

Maybe it is a bug Is there a way to check json value is null with jsonPath?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's only currently possible when explicitly setting the expected type as `Any`, using `ofType[Any]`. But you use the default, which is `String`.

We'll support all types in upcoming 2.2.1, see [issue here](https://github.com/gatling/gatling/issues/2997).